# Setting different adapter in single RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have MenuActivity which has RecyclerView and ViewPager. This ViewPager has 3 pages which use three different Fragment. 
FragmentOne,FragmentTwo, FragmentThree, All these Fragments use RecyclerView data.
I want to use three different ArrayList need to be set in RecyclerView Adapter, which is depends on what Fragment user is viewing.
One solution is to put RecyclerView in all three fragment and get update data in Fragment. I just want to know if it is possible to set Adapter data in MenuActivity based on what Fragment is called.

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        prepareMenuData();
        vegadapter = new MenuItemAdapter(getContext(),vegItemList);
        nonvegadapter = new MenuItemAdapter(getContext(),nonvegItemList);
        dessertAdapter = new MenuItemAdapter(getContext(),dessertItemList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(vegadapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



        return rootView;
    }
```

prepareMenuData();

```
        for (MenuItem item:itemList)
        {
            if(item.getCategory().equals("VEG"))
            {
                vegItemList.add(item);
                vegadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if(item.getCategory().equals("NONVEG"))
            {
                nonvegItemList.add(item);
                nonvegadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if(item.getCategory().equals("DESSERTVEG"))
            {
                dessertItemList.add(item);
                dessertAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

This code does not know when to set vegadapter,nonvegadapter etc.
Please suggest.
Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes you can, but whether thats good practice is another question.

You'll have to have the RecyclerView in each Fragment regardless but you can get the data for the adapter from the Activity. Fragments have access to their Activity, thats how the Android lifecycle works so from the Fragment you could call `((MenuActivity) getActivity()).getMenuList();` and then pass the result to that Fragments adapter. This will however couple the Fragment with the Activity which isn't good practice.

Given the fact that it looks like your data isn't dynamic what I would personally do is make your MenuItem class implement Parcelable, then when you create your Fragments you can pass through your ArrayList of MenuItems as an argument, this way your Fragment is independent of your Activity.